# Putting multiple video feed next to each other with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video, visual-c++, opencv3.0

I have real-time video from 3 different cameras, I would like to resize and then put the videos next to each other and fit them on one screen, basically:

```
-------------------------------------
| CAM LEFT | CAM MIDDLE | CAM RIGHT |
-------------------------------------
```

I have written the following code but for whatever reason I only have image on the LEFT side only. The middle and right side are replaced by a gray color background (I have no idea where that comes from). I have printed out all the coordinates and they look fine to me, with a total screen size of 1440 x 540 (I want the picture in the middle to be bigger).

```
 - LEFT:   0,0,380,540 
 - MIDDLE: 380,0,680,540
 - RIGHT:  1060,0,380,540
```

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<conio.h>           // may have to modify this line if not using Windows


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int combinedScreenWidth = 1440;
    int combinedScreenHeight = 540;
    int rearCameraBiggerByThis = 100;
    int combinedScreenWidthHalv = combinedScreenWidth / 3;

    //initialize and allocate memory to load the video stream from camera 

    cv::VideoCapture cameraRight(0);    // RIGHT CAM
    cv::VideoCapture cameraMiddle(3);   // REAR CAM
    cv::VideoCapture cameraLeft(2);     // LEFT CAM

    if (!cameraRight.isOpened())    return 1;
    if (!cameraMiddle.isOpened())   return 1;
    if (!cameraLeft.isOpened())     return 1;

    cv::Mat3b cameraRightFrame;
    cv::Mat3b cameraMiddleFrame;
    cv::Mat3b cameraLeftFrame;

    cv::Mat3b cameraRightFrameMirrored;
    cv::Mat3b cameraMiddleFrameMirrored;
    cv::Mat3b cameraLeftFrameMirrored;

    cv::Size camRightSize;
    cv::Size camMiddleSize;
    cv::Size camLeftSize;

    cv::Mat3b cameraRightFrameMirroredResize;
    cv::Mat3b cameraMiddleFrameMirroredResize;
    cv::Mat3b cameraLeftFrameMirroredResize;


    while (true) {
        // Grab
        cameraRight >> cameraRightFrame;
        cameraMiddle >> cameraMiddleFrame;
        cameraLeft >> cameraLeftFrame;

        // Mirror
        cv::flip(cameraRightFrame, cameraRightFrameMirrored, 1);
        cv::flip(cameraMiddleFrame, cameraMiddleFrameMirrored, 1);
        cv::flip(cameraLeftFrame, cameraLeftFrameMirrored, 1);

        // Resize
        camRightSize = cameraRightFrame.size();
        camMiddleSize = cameraMiddleFrame.size();
        camLeftSize = cameraLeftFrame.size();
        std::cout << "----------------------> original camRightSize " << camRightSize.width << "x" << camRightSize.height << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------> original camMiddletSize " << camMiddleSize.width << "x" << camMiddleSize.height << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------> original camLeftSize " << camLeftSize.width << "x" << camLeftSize.height << std::endl;
        resize(cameraRightFrameMirrored, cameraRightFrameMirroredResize, cv::Size(combinedScreenWidthHalv - rearCameraBiggerByThis, combinedScreenHeight));
        resize(cameraMiddleFrameMirrored, cameraMiddleFrameMirroredResize, cv::Size(combinedScreenWidthHalv + 2 * rearCameraBiggerByThis, combinedScreenHeight));
        resize(cameraLeftFrameMirrored, cameraLeftFrameMirroredResize, cv::Size(combinedScreenWidthHalv - rearCameraBiggerByThis, combinedScreenHeight));
        camRightSize = cameraRightFrameMirroredResize.size();
        camMiddleSize = cameraMiddleFrameMirroredResize.size();
        camLeftSize = cameraLeftFrameMirroredResize.size();
        std::cout << "----------------------> resized camRightSize " << camRightSize.width << "x" << camRightSize.height << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------> resized camMiddletSize " << camMiddleSize.width << "x" << camMiddleSize.height << std::endl;
        std::cout << "----------------------> resized camLeftSize " << camLeftSize.width << "x" << camLeftSize.height << std::endl;

        // Compilation   
        cv::Mat3b combinedFrame(camRightSize.height, camLeftSize.width + camMiddleSize.width + camRightSize.width);

        // LEFT
        std::cout << "LEFT: 0,0," << camLeftSize.width << "," << camLeftSize.height << std::endl;
        cv::Mat3b leftSideOfScreen(combinedFrame, cv::Rect(0, 0, camLeftSize.width, camLeftSize.height));
        cameraLeftFrameMirroredResize.copyTo(leftSideOfScreen);
        // MIDDLE
        std::cout << "MIDDLE: " << camLeftSize.width << ",0," << camMiddleSize.width << "," << camMiddleSize.height << std::endl;
        cv::Mat3b middleSideOfScreen(combinedFrame, cv::Rect(camLeftSize.width, 0, camMiddleSize.width, camMiddleSize.height));
        cameraRightFrameMirroredResize.copyTo(middleSideOfScreen);
        // RIGHT
        std::cout << "RIGHT: " << camLeftSize.width + camMiddleSize.width << ",0," << camRightSize.width << "," << camRightSize.height << std::endl;
        cv::Mat3b rightSideOfScreen(combinedFrame, cv::Rect(camLeftSize.width + camMiddleSize.width, 0, camRightSize.width, camRightSize.height));
        cameraMiddleFrameMirroredResize.copyTo(rightSideOfScreen);

        // declare windows
        cv::namedWindow("Combined", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
        cv::setWindowProperty("Combined", CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);

        cv::putText(combinedFrame, "LEFT", cv::Point(250, 50), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        cv::putText(combinedFrame, "REAR", cv::Point(650, 50), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
        cv::putText(combinedFrame, "RIGHT", cv::Point(1050, 50), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);


        cv::imshow("Combined", combinedFrame);          // 1440 x 540 Screen size
        //cv::imshow("Right Cam", cameraRightFrame);
        //cv::imshow("Middle Cam", cameraMiddleFrame);
        //cv::imshow("Left Cam", cameraLeftFrame);

                                                        //wait for 40 milliseconds
        int c = cvWaitKey(1);

        //exit the loop if user press "Esc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27) 
        if (27 == char(c)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are getting gray frame as input from cam2 and cam3, can you debug the frame grabbed by your cams ?